# AttributeError: instance has no attribute 'function'

Tags: python-2.7, class

```
class f:
def f1(self, x):
    return x
def f2(self, x):
    return 2.0*x
def f3(self, x, function=f1):
    return self.function(x)
```

then

```
>>>f0=f()
>>>f0.f3(1)
```

the error is:

```
"AttributeError: f instance has no attribute 'function'"
```

How can i fix it if i still wanna f3() to select a function of f1 or f2 in this class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`.getattr()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr):

```
class f:
    def f1(self, x):
        return x

    def f2(self, x):
        return 2.0 * x

    def f3(self, x, function="f1"):
        return getattr(self, function)(x)
```

Usage:

```
f0 = f()
print(f0.f3(1))  # prints 1
print(f0.f3(1, "f2"))  # prints 2.0
```